# Codeigniter Ajax loads only the table

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

im just new in CodeIgniter. im just wondering is it possible to apply ajax to fetch data from database in tables with pagination? i mean when i clicked the 2nd page it wont load the entire page but the table only.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: thank you @u_mulder for replying, any clue on what should i search for that kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite possible. I'll give you some skeleton, take a peek. Of course there are many ways.

*JS file:*

```
//click pagination
$('body').on('click', '.codeigniter-pagination a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.loading').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> ');
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: this.href,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $('.mediamanager__grid').html(data);
            $('.loading').empty();
        },
        error: function(e)
    {
        alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
        });

});
```

*Example controller function:*

```
public function index(
    $page_number=1, $order_by='id', $how='desc', $limit= 10
) {

    //pagination
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->picture_model->count_all();
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config['use_page_numbers']=true;
    $config['base_url'] = '/admin/mediamanager/index';
    $offset = (
        $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']) - 1
    ) * $config['per_page'];
    $offset < 0 ? $offset = 0 : '';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['pictures']=$this->picture_model
        ->limit($limit, $offset)
        ->order_by($order_by, $how)
        ->get_all();
    $this->load->view('admin/mediamanager/index', $data);
}
```

It just replaces some div with html generated, and pagination is also in that generated view. Of course, there might be bugs, f.e. I'm not sure if it was 4th or 5th segment. I'm using codeigniter-base-model , extended model library.